# mail() PHP on Private LAN

Tags: php, networking

I have created a site using PHP/MySQL and on my webserver it works fine.

However, once it was setup on a private network at my school, the mail() function ceased to work.

Any ideas? Could it be blocked by something with the ports on the network? ...

Comment: Or maybe it is disabled in the server's PHP config. I can imagine why :)

Answer (score 0):

The mail function is in the PHP file. The PHP file is on your server,  and you can call that php file from anywhere in world and it will work.
If you have moved the php file to different location it will not work.

In schools they sometimes block certain sites or features, then, yes that could be it.

Need more info, what do you mean by setup on private networK?

Answer (score 0):

The `mail()` command relies on the server's sendmail configuration, which is set in the php.ini file. Check that file on your school's server -- or if you don't have access to it, ask an admin.